# How should I set loadingRecords string or HTML element for angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

In native Datatables I set the `loadingRecords` like [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.loadingRecords):

```js
var language = {
    "loadingRecords": '<img src="~/img/datatable_loading_bar.gif" />'
}
```

When loading data, it will show datatable_loading_bar.gif

But in [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables), How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `withLanguage()` method. You are not obligated to pass an entire `language` struct, simply pass just what you need to change :

```js
.withLanguage({
   loadingRecords: '<img src="~/img/datatable_loading_bar.gif" />'
})
```