# show Loading message in angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Controller

```
  app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'dashboardService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', function ($scope, dashboardService, DTOptionsBuilder) { 
   $scope.dtMasterOptions =
    DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()       
    .withDisplayLength(10)
    .withOption('bLengthChange', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withBootstrap();       
   $scope.ViewData = function () {       
    var getData = dashboardService.getAllSubmitted();
    getData.then(function (job) {
        $scope.submitedjob = job.data;            
    },
    function (response) { document.write(response.status + "<br/>" + response.data); });
} 
 }]);
```

html code

```
       <table style="width:100%;" ng-controller='myController'>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding:25px;" ng-init=" ViewData();">
            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtMasterOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-cloak>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-danger" style="width:5%;">S. No.</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Applicant ID</th>
                        <th style="width:15%;">Email</th>
                        <th style="width:15%;">Full Name</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">Contact No</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in submitedjob" ng-if="x.SubmittedStatus==='Submitted'">
                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.ApplicantID}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Username}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Salutation}} {{x.Firstname}} {{x.Middlename}} {{x.Lastname}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Mobile}}</td>                            
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Here before data loads completely message show  'No data table avaliable' 
 So I want to show Loading message instead of  'No data avaliable' Message before my data load in datatable completely

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226074/how-should-i-set-loadingrecords-string-or-html-element-for-angular-datatables/37242515#37242515 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103524/custom-loading-in-angular-datatables/38217051#38217051

Comment: Thanks for reply @davidkonrad I tried but not work

Comment: @Pravinhow can you solve this issue. please help me to solve the same issue in angularjs
I am not using ,fromSource function 
please guide me It's very urgent for me 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

add `withOption('processing', true)` to your `DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()` and it should show Loading message.

Comment: thanks for reply  @Deendayal but  I already tried its not working

Comment: thanks its useful example  but when i tried passing like  DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(job.data)  and given from proper column name then not showing anything  why this?

Comment: you were missing the `data1.json` file. Check this. http://plnkr.co/edit/sYRSHURwsGsixPkVfhCM?p=preview

Comment: No I want to pass like  DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(dataPara) instead of file name Please check in my dataPara variable because my data come in object so i want pass 'dataPara' instead of  file name